# Cocoa: change the way cocoa reports model validation errors to user

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, validation, key-value-observing

In my Objective-C Cocoa app I have a model named `Group` with several properties (like name, description, creation date etc.), which has KVO-compliant validation methods for each of it's properties.

There is an `NSTableView` bound to `NSArrayController` and showing a list of groups which the user can modify.

Now, if I check the "*Validates immediately*" checkbox within the "*Group Name*" column's Value binding, the validation works as expected and if user enters invalid group name, an alert box is shown.

What I want to do is to suppress alert box and just mark the corresponding table row with red color.

Is it possible somehow to change the way Cocoa notifies users about validation errors?

Comment: I forgot to say, that the NSTableView is displayed within a document-modal sheet, so validation errors are reported in application-modal alerts, not in sheets (no matter if "Always presents application modal alerts" checkbox is checked or not) and that is why I want to change it as this blocks the whole application, not just currently active document window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [**Key-Value Coding Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB) :

> The validation infrastructure provides a class the opportunity to
>   accept a value, provide an alternate value, or deny the new value for
>   a property and give a reason for the error.

That's it. Other behaviour is not supported out of the box.

It shouldn't be too hard to implement custom behaviour, however:

You could e.g. provide an alternate value in case the validation fails and set some custom flag somewhere in your model that would in turn allow your table view to indicate the failed validation accordingly. Next time the value is validated and passes the validation you could then reset the flag.